# Rock, scissors, paper with Python

Tags: python

I just wrote a "Rock, scissors, paper" game in Python, but it seems it isn't working properly.

I've been searching the internet and found many different, better ways to write the code. Nonetheless, I would like to know the reason why my code doesn't check the user input against the random choice generated by the computer. Every time the user enters an option (as long as it is a valid one), the result is a tie.

I assume it will be something regarding the while loop, but I just can't figure what.

```
import random


def correct_format(x):

    x = x.upper()
    if x == "ROCK" or x == "PAPER" or x == "SCISSORS":
        return True
    else:
        return False

def pc_choice():

    number = random.randint(1,3)
    if number == 1:
        return "ROCK"
    elif number == 2:
        return "PAPER"
    else:
        return "SCISSORS"

def game():

    your_choice = input("Rock, paper, or scissors? ")
    pc_random = pc_choice()
    print("The PC has chosen " + pc_random.lower())
    print("You chose " + your_choice.lower())

    while not correct_format(your_choice):
        your_choice = input("Enter a valid option: ")
    else:
        if your_choice == "ROCK":
            if pc_random == "SCISSORS":
                print("You win!")
            elif pc_random == "PAPER":
                print("You loose")
        elif your_choice == "SCISSORS":
            if pc_random == "PAPER":
                print("You win!")
            elif pc_random == "ROCK":
                print("You loose")
        elif your_choice == "PAPER":
            if pc_random == "ROCK":
                print("You win!")
            elif pc_random == "SCISSORS":
                print("You loose")
        else:
            print("It's a tie!")

game()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [Why is "Can someone help me" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237)

Comment: Your code accepts lowercase as valid input, but then  compares with uppercase in the ifs. Example input would help clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

If the user inputs the lower case word, there's no matching `if` statement, so it defaults to the last `else`, which is a `tie`.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you are comparing lowercase values with uppercase, which have different values.

Add the line `your_choice = your_choice.upper()` before `if your_choice == "ROCK":` with proper indentation.

With this line, we convert it to uppercase and then compare.